# Large Python List Maxing out Memory (Word2Vec)

Tags: python, memory, memory-management, machine-learning, word2vec

**Some context:**
I am preparing a large input array for use in a machine learning algorithm. I am using word embeddings (using gensim and Word2Vec) to represent a 5-word sentence as a vector input. After calling the Word2Vec model on my sentence of 5 words, I will have a 500-length list of floats.

**The problem:**
I iterate through my sentences, and apply the word embedding function to them, forming a new array with the new word embedded representation. 1 word = 100 length vector of floats. I've got 1.2million sentences to encode, and when I hit around the million row mark, my 16gb RAM gets maxed out. Is there a way in which I can avoid this from happening? I have read that generators can help with memory efficiency? My first solution used numpy arrays - I changed to lists to help with memory efficiency, but I still can't complete the task. Would I have to use a cloud service to achieve this? Or can some magic be applied to the code to be able to do this on a laptop with 16Gb ram?

**The code:**

```
prev_time = time.time()
l_encodings = []
for k, sentence in enumerate(l_vocab):  # l_vocab is a list of lists where the inner list is the 5-word-sentence

    #print k, sentence
    if k % 100000 == 0:
        print k
        print time.time() - prev_time
        prev_time = time.time()

    # form list of 5-word-embedding to append to l_encodings
    for i, word in enumerate(sentence):

        if i == 0:
            l_array = model[word].tolist()  # model[word] generates a 1d numpy array of length 100
        elif i < 5:
            l_array2 = model[word].tolist()
            l_array += l_array2

    # normalise sentence lengths
    if len(l_array) != 500:
        diff = 500 - len(l_array)
        l_array += [0 for _ in range(diff)]

    print l_array
    print len(l_array)

    l_encodings.append(l_array)
```

Any help appreciated -

Comment: Depends on what you want to do next with the final encoded matrix. If just store them somewhere, then no need to keep already encoded values in memory.

Comment: Use `https://pypi.python.org/pypi/memory_profiler` to find out where your bottleneck is.. And I don't get that you switched to lists to be more memory efficient..thats the opposite.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.
@VivekKumar - so something like the following code:

with open('myfile.csv', 'a') as f:
...     for i in range(10, 100):
...             myarray = np.arange(i)
...             strarray = ','.join(map(str, myarray))
...             f.write(strarray + '\n')
...     f.close()